# Are these bends in the tub drain going to be an issue?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, code-compliance, drain-waste-vent

[image]

Im getting ready to run the drain for my basement bathroom but I'm concerned that I have too many turns in the tub drain. I had to start in the wrong direction in order to pick up a wall for a vent. Is this a problem, does it meet code? A second set of eyes on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: You put in bends where you need bends.  What do you think is this potential issue?

Comment: Unlike a commode or sink, this should be all clear water,  I do not think that it will be an issue.  I do not see a vent for the commode.

Comment: The commode will use a wet vent from the sink, that is the reason for the 2" drain below the lav trap arm.

Comment: @fixer1234 The potential issue I guess would be either a clogged drain ( which i guess is unlikely as Jim pointed out) or not meeting code. I've read people saying you need a clean out if you go over 135 total degrees, I can't find that in the code though.